# Spring Boot Swagger REST Server Unreachable at Port 6000 Due to localhost not secure error

Tags: security, server, localhost, port

I'm trying to launch a server at localhost:6000. When I run it at localhost:8080, it runs fine, but at localhost:6000, Chrome tells me my connection is not secure. I have another server running at 8080, so I don't want to use that port.

I tried going to chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost and enabling it. Then I restarted my browser, but that didn't help. I couldn't get to it on Firefox either.

I can reach the connection using Postman, so I know the server is working correctly at that port. But that just gives me the raw HTML. I need to bring the pages up in my browser. Does anyone know what I can do?

(I'm using the current Chrome v69, on a Mac with OSX 10.11.6. I built my server using Spring Boot and Swagger.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than go to the trouble of launching Chrome with a command-line option, a simpler solution was to just use a different port. Of all the 4-digit numbers, 6000 is one of only 9 that are blocked by Chrome. Chrome blocks these: 2049, 3659, 4045, 6000, 6665, 6666, 6667, 6668, and 6669. Firefox also blocks some of these, but their list is shorter. A lot of 2- and 3-digit numbers are also blocked, but we shouldn't be using numbers below 1024 anyway. Here's a page with links to the lists of blocked ports: https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-on-chrome

Answer (score 1):

I have followed following link and I got my localhost accessed from port "6000"
https://douglastarr.com/how-to-allow-unsafe-ports-in-chrome

try running chrome with either this command from cmd 
\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --explicitly-allowed-ports=6060
or put the lines above in bat file and run it.

Comment: Thank you. The instructions in the link seem to assume I'm running on Windows. But from my other investigations, I've learned that the real problem is that I just happened to choose one of only 9 of the 4-digit port numbers that are blocked. The simplest solution was to switch to another port number.
For the record, here's where I found out which port numbers are blocked: https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-on-chrome